# How does special relativity account for intrinsic magnetic moments and orbital magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I've just watched this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM

And it makes perfect sense to me.
The only thing that I don't understand is how orbital magnetic fields or intrinsic magnetic moments of charged particles can be accounted for in the same way.

I mean, an electron is orbiting a positive nucleus. If some charged particle flew past that atom real fast parallel to the orbit of the electron, then maybe yes, for a very brief moment, an electron would appear static to it while the nucleus would move past it real fast and thus would appear shrunk... but there's only one nucleus, so in no way that shrinking would entail that more positive charge would be packed along the path of the particle.

And intrinsic magnetic momentum is absolutely unclear to me... I mean, if it's an electron we're talking about, then there is no positive charge at all, and nothing is moving nowhere. So what's getting stretched and what's not?

Comment: Please do not expect readers to watch a video in order to understand your question. Can you describe *what* “makes perfect sense”?

Comment: The video shows how special relativity explains magnetic field created by a current running through wire. If a positively charged particle ran parallel to the wire, from it's perspective it would seem that electron current in the wire is static, but positively charged parts move in the opposite direction - and since they move, they appear shrunk according to special relativity, and hence more positive charge fits in the same length than negative, and the particle is repelled. I.e., there is no magnetic force, but an electrostatic force that affects only moving particles due to relativity.

Comment: It makes perfect sense, but doesn't seem to explain at all the magnetism created by electrons orbiting atom nuclei, or intrinsic magnetic moment of particles.

Comment: Not all magnetism is due to relativistic effects. Even in classical electrodynamics $Val = E^2-c^2 B^2$ is invariant, i.e. has the same value irrespective of the observer. Where $E$ is electric field, $B$ is magnetic field and $c$ is the speed of light. So if $Val$ is negative for one observer, it will be equally negative for all observers. Thus magnetic field will not be fully explained by electric field irrespective of the observer.

Comment: This does not quite answer your question, but I felt it is a relevent point to make. Going into QM will only create more confusion.